Why is append returning a string?
The Describe Function (Ctrl-h f) documentation for the append function says

append is a built-in function in ‘src/fns.c’.
(append &rest SEQUENCES)
Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 18.   This function
does not change global state, including the match data.
Concatenate all the arguments and make the result a list. The
result is a list whose elements are the elements of all the arguments.
Each argument may be a list, vector or string. The last argument is
not copied, just used as the tail of the new list.

But this code:
(progn
  (setq my-var (append nil "5"))
  (if (listp my-var)
      (message "It's a list!")
      (message "It's not a list..."))
  (if (stringp my-var)
      (message "my-var is a string??")))

prints "my-var is a string??" in the status bar. Is my check wrong or did append return a string rather than a list?
I get the same behavior if I use '() instead of nil for the first argument.

Wrt your last sentence: in Elisp, (), aka nil, is self-evaluating, so you never need to quote it.

Yes, in this case append returned a string, not a list.
Yes, this particular case isn't explicitly mentioned in the doc, which is thus misleading in this case.

The first line of a doc string gives (only) a summary description. You often need to read the whole doc string for more complete information. And you sometimes need to consult the Elisp manual for even more complete/exact information.  C-h f append says:

append is a built-in function in C source code.
(append &rest SEQUENCES)
Concatenate all the arguments and make the result a list.
The result is a list whose elements are the elements of all the arguments.
Each argument may be a list, vector or string.
All arguments except the last argument are copied.  The last argument
is just used as the tail of the new list.

The doc string doesn't explicitly say that nil arguments are ignored, and it doesn't explicitly say that if all args but the last are nil then the last arg is returned as is, regardless of what it is -- it need not even be a sequence.
Elisp manual node Building Lists says this about append:

-- Function: append &rest sequences
This function returns a list containing all the elements of
SEQUENCES.  The SEQUENCES may be lists, vectors, bool-vectors, or
strings, but the last one should usually be a list.  All arguments
except the last one are copied, so none of the arguments is
altered.  (See nconc in *note Rearrangement::, for a way to join
lists with no copying.)
More generally, the final argument to append may be any Lisp
object.  The final argument is not copied or converted; it becomes
the CDR of the last cons cell in the new list.  If the final
argument is itself a list, then its elements become in effect
elements of the result list.  If the final element is not a list,
the result is a dotted list since its final CDR is not nil as
required in a proper list (*note Cons Cells::).
Here is an example of using append:
 (setq trees '(pine oak))
  ⇒ (pine oak)
 (setq more-trees (append '(maple birch) trees))
  ⇒ (maple birch pine oak)

 trees
  ⇒ (pine oak)
 more-trees
  ⇒ (maple birch pine oak)
 (eq trees (cdr (cdr more-trees)))
  ⇒ t

You can see how append works by looking at a box diagram.  The
more-trees                    trees
    |                           |
    |     --- ---      --- ---   -> --- ---      --- ---
     --> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> |   |   |--> nil
          --- ---      --- ---      --- ---      --- ---
           |            |            |            |
           |            |            |            |
            --> maple    -->birch     --> pine     --> oak

An empty sequence contributes nothing to the value returned by
append.  As a consequence of this, a final nil argument forces a
copy of the previous argument:
 trees
     ⇒ (pine oak)
 (setq wood (append trees nil))
     ⇒ (pine oak)
 wood
     ⇒ (pine oak)
 (eq wood trees)
     ⇒ nil

This once was the usual way to copy a list, before the function
copy-sequence was invented.  *Note Sequences Arrays Vectors::.
Here we show the use of vectors and strings as arguments to append:
 (append [a b] "cd" nil)
     ⇒ (a b 99 100)

With the help of apply (*note Calling Functions::), we can append
all the lists in a list of lists:
 (apply 'append '((a b c) nil (x y z) nil))
     ⇒ (a b c x y z)

If no SEQUENCES are given, nil is returned:
 (append)
     ⇒ nil

Here are some examples where the final argument is not a list:
 (append '(x y) 'z)
     ⇒ (x y . z)
 (append '(x y) [z])
     ⇒ (x y . [z])

The second example shows that when the final argument is a sequence but
not a list, the sequence’s elements do not become elements of the
resulting list.  Instead, the sequence becomes the final CDR, like any
other non-list final argument.

The last two examples correspond to your example, which uses a string as the last argument instead of a symbol or a vector:

 (append '(x y) "z")
     ⇒ (x y . "z")


The sequence (string) "z" becomes the last cdr of the resulting sequence. In your case, the first sequence argument, which is nil, has no effect on the result, as is always the case for a nil argument. The result is the sequence (string) "5", which is the last (second) argument to append.
See also the general definition of a list in Elisp (node Cons Cells): it includes a dotted list, not just a proper/true list (whose last cdr is nil).

However, the doc does say that the result is always a list.  That seems like a doc bug in the particular case that only the last argument is non-nil and it is not a proper list. I've now submitted Emacs bug #73427 for this.
UPDATE: The bug was fixed by Eli immediately.
This Common Lisp doc and the Common Lisp Hyperspec make your case clear. Note the last sentence and the last example.

append Function
Syntax:
append &rest lists → result
Arguments and Values:
lists — each must be a proper list except the last, which may be any object.
`result — an object. This will be a list unless the last list was not a list and all preceding lists were null.
Description:
append returns a new list that is the concatenation of the copies. lists are left unchanged; the list structure of each of lists except the last is copied.
The last argument is not copied; it becomes the cdr of the final dotted pair of the concatenation of the preceding lists, or is returned directly if there are no preceding non-empty lists.
Examples:
(append ’(a b c) ’(d e f) ’() ’(g)) → (A B C D E F G) 
(append ’(a b c) ’d) → (A B C . D) 
(setq lst ’(a b c)) → (A B C) 
(append lst ’(d)) → (A B C D) 
lst → (A B C) 
(append) → NIL 
(append ’a) → A 



Doc string?? I had the ctrl-h f output in my question.

Yes, you do show it. But as I explain, the first line of a doc string isn't always complete, and even the complete doc string isn't always the full explanation. The Elisp manual is more complete in this case, and even that doesn't explicitly mention the case you cite. I've file a doc bug for that.

Doesn't it look like the drawing of the list has "trees" pointing to the wrong node?

Yes, thanks. I've fixed that now. I had to convert the text from the Emacs buffer to StackExchange input formatting. The diagram doesn't show too well here, admittedly.

The primitive function append calls C function concat_to_list, which contains:
  if (NILP (result))
    result = last_tail;

This is why the last string is simply returned.

Thus (append anything) returns anything.  Don't rely on this behavior!

The documentation lists string as one of the possible arguments: "Each argument may be a list, vector or string. " Although the documentation only talks about a list being returned, which is not the case.

@Scooter: Oops... I kept only the second paragraph of the original answer now. I think this is a bug, you can report it, or I can report it for you.

This answer shows the C implementation (a "how" explanation), but it doesn't speak to what the intended behavior is or why. The behavior isn't a bug - Lisp has long had this behavior for append. But the doc doesn't explicitly address this case -- a doc bug, IMO. And you can rely on this behavior.

@Drew: "it doesn't speak to what the intended behavior is or why." -- You does.  Thanks.  I've upvoted your answer.
